# msdeploy inside visual studio publish profile

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, publish, msdeploy

How do i use my custom msdeploy and msbuild community task script from VS 2010 web deployment project inside a visual studio 2012 publish profile?

My script in VS2010 builds to a local directory and then makes a few modifications to the generated files and sends it up. This is all tied to the specific configuration that is selected for example: Test, stage, production configurations.

For some reason i cannot see how this plays out using the publish feature in VS 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VS 2012 you can have a core web.config and then multiple web.configs for each configuration that you build such as web.debug.config etc.

When you build and publish, based on the configuration you choose a web.config is generated on the fly which combines the parent web.config and the configuration specific web.config (based on what you specify, replace, add etc).

Then msdeploy is invoked to generate a web deploy package of this which is of type iisApp by default unless you specify include IIS settings.

This package is deployed to the server you specify. If you have database connection strings etc, they will be replaced during publish to the server side values if you have specified them using web deploy parameterization.

Comment: This didnt really answer how to use msdeploy within the publish profile but thank you for the response!  i did although figure it out.  The msdepoy commands dont need to be imported as they do in vs2010 its just built right in. So i can copy past my custom script right in and use the beforepublish and afterpublish targets.  I havent found yet if there is a publish target that you can high jack and take over the processing that would normally happen.